# Haskell: use Maybe but print an actual number rather than "Just ... "

Tags: haskell, max

So here is my program. I want to implement a maximum function on my own for an assignment. The problem is that to me it seems weird to print the number with the word "Just" in front of it... How would I fix this to print just a number?

```
mymax :: Ord a=>[a]->Maybe a
mymax [] = Nothing
mymax [x] = Just x
mymax (x:y:xs) = if x < y then mymax(y:xs) else mymax(x:xs)
```

Comment: what will you print if you gave empty list?

Comment: Gabriel Gonzalez wrote the [optional](http://www.haskellforall.com/2015/06/optional-args-100-optional-function.html) package to provide this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well the `Show` instance for `Maybe` puts that `Just` there. If you don't want it the simple solution is to not use `show`

```
myPrint :: Show a => Maybe a -> IO ()
myPrint (Just x) = print x
myPrint n        = print n
```

Here we just unwrap `Just`s before tossing them to `print`.

The other option is to lose the `Maybe`. You can either do this with something like `maybe`

```
maybe (putStrLn "Nothing") print m

printMay = maybe (putStrLn "Nothing") print
```

This takes a value `m :: Maybe a` and if it's `Just x` tosses `x` to `print`. Otherwise it simply returns `putStrLn "Nothing"`.

Answer (score 3):

You have a ton of alternatives here! This following solution is exactly what you asked for, no more, no less: *

```
printMaybe :: Show a => Maybe a -> IO ()
printMaybe m = when (isJust m) $
                 print (fromJust m)
```

This will print the argument maybe value if it is a `Just` value, and otherwise do nothing at all. However, it's not the greatest of solutions in most cases. Any time you see `fromJust` you should regard it as a red flag. In this case, the problem is that the `Nothing` case is not handled at all. We would probably want to inform the user or at least do *something* when the list was empty. Then again, maybe we don't, and then this solution is fine.

Another case is if you would want to print something when the value is `Nothing`, in which case you can use the `maybe` function.

```
printMaybe m = maybe (putStrLn "List was empty!") print m
```

This will print "List was empty!" if `m` contains `Nothing`, otherwise it will print `m`. This is of course equivalent to

```
printMaybe = maybe (putStrLn "List was empty!") print
```

You could also implement this with pattern matching manually, like so:

```
printMaybe m = case m of
  Nothing -> putStrLn "List was empty!"
  Just x -> print x
```

which is equivalent, but slightly more code. In the same vein, you could explicitly do

```
printMaybe m = case m of
  Nothing -> return ()
  Just x -> print x
```

if you want the function to not do anything at all when it gets a `Nothing` value, like the first function in my answer.

---

* This could be written more neatly by using the applicative instance of functions, like this:

```
printMaybe = liftA2
  when isJust $ print . fromJust
```

This does quite literally what it reads as. "**When** the argument **is** a **Just**, **print** what you get **from** the **Just**."

Comment: will it be idiomatic to `fail "List was empty!"` instead of `putStrLn "List was empty!"`? to let the caller deal with empty lists, if they were not meant to occur there?

Comment: @SassaNF That's just as good (or bad) as `printMaybe m = print (fromJust m)`. In general, you want to avoid exceptions in Haskell code.

Comment: on the other hand, I see `Alternative` needs `empty`, which often is `fail`, if it is a Monad. Is this intuition right?

Comment: @SassaNF: I think your intuition is backwards on this.  You don't want to use `fail` because for certain monads (`IO`, `Identity`, and many others) all `fail` does is raise an exception, which should generally be avoided in pure Haskell code.  However, for monads which have a sensible `empty` (`Maybe`,`[]`), calling `fail` should produce that empty value.  If you need it, you should use an `Alternative` or `MonadSum` constraint and call `empty` or `mzero` instead of `fail`.

Comment: @JohnL you are right, the monads that don't have `empty` don't implement `Alternative`. I thought `fail` is useful in the sense that it can add messages to the monoid of log, which empty and mzero cannot. I think maybe I should post this as a separate question.

Comment: Since you've already gone to `Applicative`, why not `when . isJust <*> print . fromJust` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`fromJust`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html#v%3afromJust)`:: Maybe a -> a` function. That will convert `Just 4` into `4` for example. Be careful though, if you call `fromJust Nothing` it will throw an error.

To avoid the error, use `fromMaybe`, which takes a default value that will be returned if you pass a `Nothing` value to the function.

Comment: It is not advisable to use `fromJust`, as he could have defined the function without using `Maybe` in the first place throwing error for the empty case.